# ace:datatable filter listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, ace-editor

I am using a ace:datatable (in my jsf project).
Inside this table I have a select box, which I want to be like [this](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/), I have implemented it on my page, All select boxes are show as expected.

but when I(user) filter data on ace:datatable (in browser) that boxes are shown as simple select boxes. It happens because that select tags get loaded again, and I need to call a jquery method to show that select boxes as drop down list (as per above link),

So I want to know is there any way to call javascript function when data in datatable changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented custom filter for datatable.
I placed some inputboxes outside the datatable, and on valuchangelistener of this inputs I am doing filter process on data stored in vector (data for datatable) and then I am calling a javascript function from there to rebuild all dropdownlists.